# how to insert difference between two hours in sql statement?

Tags: mysql, database

It is so frustrating that Mysql doesnot support procedure language..

Problem i have two time variables in mySql tables time1 and time 2, I have another time variable column which is diffTime. diffTime stores the time interval between time 1 and time 2. Now I need an insert statement like this :
insert into Table(time1, time2, diffTime) value(time1, time2, diffbetween(time1 and time2))

is there a way to solve this problem, Also additionally how to use procedure language in PhpMyAdmin....

Many thanks

Comment: Getting time difference in MySql is as easy as it can be. Why typing all this while simple search will give you an answer?

Comment: are they timestamps or datetime btw. dont melt over it snowman

Comment: i am getting too frustrated now.. so much work to do .. i cant remember small things... anyway.. the time is a time variable in the PhpMyadmin sql database. its not datetime nore timestamps but rather its simply a time variable..

Comment: type "describe my_table_name;"  (btw chg the name) and paste it here. anyway, it is 3am in London. go to bed

Comment: Also paste sample data (one or two rows) from that table

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on type of `time1` and `time2` and what kind of difference you need to get, but you can use [`TIMEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) or [`DATEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

```
INSERT INTO `table` (time1, time2, diffTime) 
SELECT time1, time2, TIMEDIFF(time2, time1)
  FROM othertable
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4cdb/1)**